# How do I pick the time in an MUI DateTimePicker using @testing-library/react and @testing-library/user-event?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to write a test involving the `DateTimePicker` using `@testing-library/react`/`@testing-library/user-event`.

This is how I'm opening the picker and picking a date:

```js
it('test picker', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2022-12-15T14:03:23Z'));
    render((
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns as any}>
            <MyComponentContainingADateTimePicker />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    ));

    // Open the picker
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'Choose date'}));
    // Pick a day in the current month
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('gridcell', {name: '16'}));
    // Pick hours
    userEvent.selectOptions(
        screen.getByRole('listbox'),
        screen.getByRole('option', {name: '20 hours'}),
        undefined,
        {skipPointerEventsCheck: true},
    );
    // Pick minutes
    userEvent.selectOptions(
        screen.getByRole('listbox'),
        screen.getByRole('option', {name: '00 minutes'}),
        undefined,
        {skipPointerEventsCheck: true},
    );
});
```

Problem 1: I have to use `skipPointerEventsCheck: true` because the `listbox` and `option`s aren't clickable.

Problem 2: The picker doesn't advance to the minutes when I pick the hours (probably because of problem 1)

Comment: I'm using the `DateTimePicker` and notice Problem 2. Did you ever find a solution for that?

Comment: @riqitang nope, sorry.